# How to SELECT and UNION from a group of Tables in the schema in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a group of tables in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database, all of them with the same columns.

I need to `SELECT` and `UNION` these tables. I can `SELECT` the tables I want like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables
where (TABLE_NAME like '%_CH1' or TABLE_NAME like '%_CH0')
and TABLE_NAME not like '%test%'
```

What I need now is to `SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3` from the first guy in that list, `UNION SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3` from the next guy in that list and so forth.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why don't you just select directly from the tables?  Why are you using the `information_schema.tables` to get the table names?

Comment: Do you want to generate dynamic sql query?

Comment: @bluefeet - I'm not selecting directing from the tables because (a) the list is long and (b) there are new tables that are created every couple of weeks, and I don't want to manually go and add them to the list. Makes sense?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - whatever is needed to get the job done.

Comment: Wait, why are you creating tables with identical schema instead of using a single table with an additional field that determines what group the records belong to (e.g., a date)?  Tables shouldn't be treated like batch record sets precisely because the database can't work with them and you end up with gross situations like this. Is there a reason for it?

Comment: @Amarundo are the columns actually named `column1`, `column2` and `column3` or are they different in each table?

Comment: @BaconBits - that's the way it is for the system I'm working with. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic query example;

```
--CREATE TABLE Utable1 (Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT)
--CREATE TABLE Utable2 (Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT)
--CREATE TABLE Utable3 (Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT)


DECLARE  @SelectClause  VARCHAR(100)    = 'SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3'
        ,@Query         VARCHAR(1000)   = '' 

SELECT @Query = @Query + @SelectClause + ' FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + ' UNION ALL '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE (TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_CH1' OR TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_CH0')
AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%test%'

SELECT @Query = LEFT(@Query, LEN(@Query) - LEN(' UNION ALL '))

EXEC (@Query)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much. The taking out of the last UNION ALL is great. Just for the next people seeing your answer, you may want to edit and add 'SELECT ' +  before @ColumnList.

Comment: You're welcome :) I changed the variable name instead - I'm hardcore like that ^^

Comment: Use  nvarchar(max) as your variables types.

Answer (score 3):

[@MarkD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160038/how-to-select-and-union-from-a-group-of-tables-in-the-schema-in-sql-2008-r2/14160497#14160497) will work great if the column names are identical, but if the column names are different, then you will need to query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get the column names.

This is version that should work as well:

```
select row_number() over(order by (select 1)) id, table_name
into #tempTables
from information_schema.tables
where table_name like 'Table%'

declare @tempColumns table
(
    id int,
    column_name varchar(50),
    table_name varchar(50)
) 

declare @query varchar(max) = ''
declare @rownum int = 1
declare @maxrownum int = (select max(id) from #temptables)
declare @table varchar(50)

declare @colrow int = 1

while @rownum <= @maxrownum
  begin
    set @table = (select TABLE_NAME from #tempTables where id = @rownum)

    set @query = @query + ' SELECT '

    insert into @tempColumns    
    select row_number() over(order by (select 1)) id, COLUMN_NAME, @table
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_NAME = @table
        and ORDINAL_POSITION in (1, 2, 3)

        -- reset colrow to 1
        set @colrow = 1

        while @colrow <= 3
            begin

                set @query = @query + (select Column_name 
                                        from @tempColumns 
                                        where id = @colrow
                                            and table_name = @table) + ' as Col' + CAST(@colrow as varchar(50))

                if @colrow < 3
                    set @query = @query + ', '

                if @colrow <= 3
                    set @colrow = @colrow + 1

            end

    set @query = @query + ' FROM ' + @table

    if @rownum < @maxrownum
        set @query = @query + ' UNION ALL '

    if @rownum <= @maxrownum
        set @rownum = @rownum + 1
  end

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d4bf/1)

Comment: The column names are identical. Thanks!