# How to SELECT and UNION from a group of tables in schema in SQL Server 2008 R2 using a variable to define the database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This is a progression from the question asked here: [How to SELECT and UNION from a group of Tables in the schema in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14160038/10205365)

I would like to do very much the same thing and the answer given by MarkD works perfectly for the database I am currently working with. Although admittedly I'd like to understand exactly how. How does the query below build the union query from the list of tables returned by the information_schema?

```
    DECLARE @Select_Clause varchar(600) = N'SELECT [Patient_Number] AS [ID number]
    ,[Attendance Date] AS [Date Seen]
    ,[Attendance_Type] AS [New/Follow up]
    ,[Episode Type] AS [Patient Type]
    ,[Local Authority District]
    ,Postcode, N''Shaw'' AS Clinic '
    ,@Where_Clause varchar(100) = N' WHERE [EPISODE TYPE] LIKE N''HIV'''                                  
    ,@Union_Clause varchar(100) = N' UNION ALL '
    ,@Query       nvarchar(max) = N''
    ,@RawDataBase varchar(50) = N'BHT_1819_RawData'
    ,@Schema      varchar(50) = N'HIVGUM'
    ,@Table_Count tinyint;

DECLARE @Table_Count_def nvarchar(100) = N'@TableSchema varchar(50)
    ,@Table_CountOUT tinyint OUTPUT'
    ,@Start_Position int = LEN(REPLACE(@Select_Clause, N' ', N'-'))
    ,@Length int; 

SET @Query = N'SELECT @Table_CountOUT = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @RawDataBase + 
    N'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE @TableSchema';

EXEC sp_executesql @query, @Table_Count_def, @TableSchema=@Schema, 
    @Table_CountOUT=@Table_Count OUTPUT;
SET @Query = N'';


IF @Table_Count > 0 
Begin
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.HIV_Cumulative', N'U') is not null
        DROP TABLE dbo.HIV_Cumulative;

    SELECT @Query = @Query + @Select_Clause + N' FROM ' + @RawDataBase + 
        N'.HIVGUM.' + TABLE_NAME + @Where_Clause + @Union_Clause
    FROM BHT_1819_RawData.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE @Schema;

    SET @Length = LEN(REPLACE(@query, N' ', N'-')) - @Start_Position - 
        LEN(REPLACE(@Where_Clause + @Union_Clause, N' ', N'-'));

    SELECT @Query = SUBSTRING(@QUERY , @Start_Position+1, @Length)

    SET @Query = @Select_Clause + N' INTO BHT_SLR..HIV_Cumulative ' + @QUERY 
        + @Where_Clause;

    EXEC sp_executesql @Query
End
ELSE
    PRINT N'No tables present in database ' + @RawDataBase + N' for Schema ' + 
        @Schema + N'. You must import source data first.';
```

The added complication is that I am querying the tables on a separate DB - currently BHT_1819_RawData - so have hard coded the database where it queries the information_schema. What I would really like to do is to specify the separate database using a variable. So that it can be reconfigured to extract from BHT_1920_RawData. I am fairly familiar with exec and sp_executesql, but have only occasionally used output parameters so am not sure what is required here. The attempts that I have made haven't worked. Once I have got this right, I will need to create several other similar scripts that work on the same principle.

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? Maybe you should print or select @Query before executing it? Then you will notice that your dynamic sql is missing the schema on the remote server.

Comment: Are you suggesting that you want to union the results from selecting multiple tables from multiple databases?  If so, that can be done, but it will be a bit trickier.  I don't want to post an answer until I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: To answer the "How does it work part", this clause `@Query = @Query + ...` works like a sort of recursive query where it keeps appending each ... to the end of the @query variable for each row.

Comment: Thanks Tom. And getting results from multiple databases does sound complicated. No, it is just one database at a time fortunately. I just want to be able to specify that database using a variable. The schema within the database that contains the tables will remain constant.

Answer (score 0):

Once I realised what needed to happen, I went through some trial and error and came up with a solution:

```
SET @ParmDef = N'@QueryOut nvarchar(2500) OUTPUT';
SET @sql_string = N'SELECT @QueryOut = @QueryOut + N''' 
                  + @Select_Clause + ' FROM ' 
                  + @RawDataBase 
                  + N'.[' + @Schema + N'].'' + TABLE_NAME + N''  '
                  + @Where_Clause 
                  + @Union_Clause
                  + N''' FROM ' 
                  + @RawDataBase 
                  + N'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE ''' 
                  + @Schema 
                  + N''' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE N''%_YTD%''';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql_string, @ParmDef, @QueryOut=@Query OUTPUT;

SET @Length = LEN(REPLACE(@query, N' ', N'-')) - @Start_Position - 
    LEN(REPLACE(@Where_Clause + @Union_Clause, N' ', N'-'));

SELECT @Query = SUBSTRING(@QUERY , @Start_Position, @Length+1);

SET @Query = REPLACE(@Select_Clause, N'''''', '''') + N' INTO ' + @New_Table + N' ' + 
    @QUERY + REPLACE(@Where_Clause, N'''''', '''');

EXEC sp_executesql @Query;
```