# SQL - Get percentage of empty rows in all columns with integer and varchar columns?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, redash

I have a table with 300+ columns and I want to see if there is a way to get percentage of empty rows in each of the columns. I wanted to pull the data using Python and then write a function. However, there are 400,000,000+ rows so that is not feasible. So now I am using sum and case when statements to get the percentage of each column manually like so:

```
select (100.0 * sum(case when A = ' ' or A is null then 1 else 0 end)) / count(*) as A
       ,(100.0 * sum(case when B is null then 1 else 0 end)) / count(*) as B
       ,(100.0 * sum(case when C = ' ' or C is null then 1 else 0 end)) / count(*)  as C
       ,(100.0 * sum(case when D = ' ' or D is null then 1 else 0 end)) / count(*)  D
       ,(100.0 * sum(case when E = ' ' or E is null then 1 else 0 end)) / count(*)  E
       ,(100.0 * sum(case when F is null then 1 else 0 end)) / count(*) as F
       ....
from table
```

I have done this for about 30 columns, but I am trying to see if there is a way to do this across all the columns in the table. Some columns contain integers so I can't use

```
 case when C = ' ' or C is null then 1 else 0 end
```

I have to use

```
 case when C is null then 1 else 0 end
```

Is there a way to continue using this logic, where the case statement changes depending on the type of column and get the percentages for all columns? Thanks.

Comment: You can create a `Dynamic query` (a query which generate another query) using [table columns information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_GET_COLS.html).

Comment: I don't see how this is going to help me.

Comment: @nachospiu all it does is show me column types

Comment: You can get columns name and type and create a query using this information. I don't have access to a redshift database to make a query for you. This is a [Postgresql dynamic query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69318683/15424227), so you have an idea how to make it, but it is different for each RDBMS.

Comment: A quick [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b6da3ba650716058d51a16981e44c42b), that resolve your problem in Postgresql so you can see how a dynamic query works.

Comment: If you shared the `CREATE TABLE` statement, maybe I can write the query you are looking for (using other RDBMS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this problem involved using Python and Redshift. Not sure if this is the best way to do it but this is what worked for me.

I first used the function from @nachospiu's comment 'pg_get_cols' to get all the column names

```
query = '''select col_name
            from pg_get_cols("schema.table") 
            cols(view_schema name, view_name name, col_name name, col_type varchar, col_num int)
            '''
cols = pd.read_sql_query(query, rsm.dbengine)
```

Then once I had all the column names, I created a for loop to get the percentage of each column using a try and except statement so that it would not fail if the column was not varchar type.

```
nulls = {}
for col in cols.col_name:
    try: 
        que = '''select (100.0 * sum(case when {} = ' ' or {} is null then 1 else 0 end)) / count(*) as perc
                 from schema.table
                '''.format(col, col)
        perc = pd.read_sql(que, rsm.dbengine).perc.values[0]
        nulls[col] = perc
    
    except: 
        
        que = '''select (100.0 * sum(case when  {} is null then 1 else 0 end)) / count(*) as perc
                 from schema.table
                '''.format(col)
        perc = pd.read_sql(que, rsm.dbengine).perc.values[0]
        nulls[col] = perc
```

This produced a dictionary that allowed me to view the percentage of nulls for each column.